# Pasted an object from a webpage (a button) into Excel Spreadsheet, can't delete it

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a very important spreadsheet, and I attempted to copy some data from a webpage into it. What I really ended up doing was copying over a button. When I click the button in Excel it seems to press, but doesn't do anything. When I tap on it, nearly everything in the toolbar goes gray, and I can hardly select any options. I've tried using Find & Select objects, but it can't find the button. It seems like it's floating above the spreadsheet.

[image]

Comment: Restore from your backup or last saved version.

Comment: add an image to your post, show us what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I saved and closed the page, and once Excel opened it back up it had removed the image on its own.

Comment: Friendly reminder to mark your answer as 'the' answer.